# Help in this proof of Legendre symbols

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I need help in the second part of this theorem:

[image]
[image]

I didn't understand the second part of this theorem:

1. Why can we choose such $j$ and $j'$?
2. What does the author mean by "the combined contribution $j$ and $j'$ to $(p-1)!$ is $jj'\equiv a (\mod p)$"?
3. why are there $(p-1)/2$ such pairs?

I really need help and I would be very grateful if someone could help me.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We give what is essentially the same proof, but the wording will be different. I take it that you had no trouble with the part of the proof that says that if the Legendre symbol $(a/p)$ is $1$, meaning that $a$ is a QR of $p$, then $a^{(p-1)/2}\equiv 1 \pmod{p}$.

We want to show that if $(a/p)=-1$, meaning that $a$ is a NR of $p$, then $a^{(p-1)/2}\equiv -1\pmod{p}$.

Look at the numbers from $1$ to $p-1$. If $x$ and $y$ are in this interval, call $x$ and $y$ **partners** if $xy\equiv a\pmod{p}$. First we show that every $y$ has a partner. Since $y$ and $p$ are relatively prime, by **Bézout's identity** there exist integers $s$ and $t$ such that $sy+tp=1$. It follows that $(as)y+atp=a$, and therefore 
$$(as)y\equiv a\pmod{p}.$$
Let $x$ be the remainder when $as$ is divided by $p$. Then $1\le x\le p-1$ and $xy\equiv a \pmod{p}$. This $x$ is the partner of $y$. The $x$ is unique, for if $xy\equiv x'y\equiv a \pmod{p}$ then by cancellation $x\equiv x'\pmod{p}$.

Note that $y$ is never her own partner, for if she were we would have $y^2\equiv a\pmod{p}$, contradicting the fact that $a$ is a NR of $p$.

Thus the numbers from $1$ to $p-1$ are divided into couples. There are obviously $(p-1)/2$ couples, since there are $p-1$ people.

The product of the two numbers in any couple is congruent to $a$ modulo $p$. This is by the definition of couplehood.

There are $(p-1)/2$ couples, each of which has product congruent to $a$. So the product of **all** the numbers in the interval $1$ to $p-1$ is congruent to $a^{(p-1)/2}$ modulo $p$. But by Wilson's Theorem the product of all the numbers from $1$ to $p-1$ is congruent to $-1$ modulo $p$.

It follows that $a^{(p-1)/2}\equiv -1\pmod{p}$.

Comment: Why there is a $x$ such that $x\equiv ay^{-1}\pmod{p}$? and why this implies $xy\equiv a\pmod{p}$? thanks

Comment: If $\gcd(y,p)=1$, then there exist $s$ and $t$ such that $sy+tp=1$. Thus $sy\equiv 1\pmod p$. The $s$ is the inverse of $y$. If $x\equiv ay^{-1}$, then $xy\equiv ay^{-1}y\equiv a$ because $y^{-1}y\equiv 1$.

Comment: Very clear explanation, but I still don't understand why there is a $x$ such that $x\equiv ay^{-1}\pmod{p}$

Comment: OK, another way, related. Fix $y$, $1\le y\le p-1$. You know the theorem that there exist $s$, $t$ such that $sy+tp=1$. Multiply by $a$. We get $(as)y+ap=a$. Thus $(as)y\equiv a \pmod{p}$. If we let $x$ be the remainder when $as$ is divided by $p$, then $x$ is the partner of $y$.

Comment: $(a,p)=1$? I'm asking that because I already know that $(s,p)=1$ and I need this $(as,p)=1$ to use the cancellation law here: $xy(as)\equiv a(as)\pmod{p}$

Comment: $a$ is a quadratic non-residue, so it cannot be divisible by $p$. Actually, residues can't be either. Though $0$ is a square, it is not called a QR, and it is certainly not called a NR.

Comment: Thank you very much, you helped me a lot!!! Great answer!

Comment: You are welcome.